# Could you provide feedback on my LTC2954 and TPS61090 Schematic?

Tags: pcb-design, switches, switch-mode-power-supply, ldo, switching-regulator

I am a hobbyist diving a bit deeper into designing more complex PCBs. In the past, I have created basic ESP32 based 2 layer PCBs with basic LDOs for supplying power. I am currently working on a more complex PCB which requires 5V and 3.3V. I have chosen to use the TPS61090 to supply the 5V and then use a AP2112k-3.3 to supply the 3.3V. In addition to this, I have also included the LTC2954-1 which acts as a latching circuit for a momentary push which I would like it to turn off the TPS61090 when the LTC2954-1 is in the off state.

Could someone review my schematic? Have I connected the LTC2954-1 to the enable pin of the TPS61090 correctly? Any feedback on my schematic would be much appreciated.

[image: Electronic Schematic]

Comment: Have you simulated any relevant parts of the circuit?

Comment: Hi Andy, to be honest I haven't and wouldn't really know where to start. Can you do that in KiCAD? Is there any free software that I could use that I can simulate it that isn't too hard for a beginner?

Comment: If LTC2954-1 is there just for ordinary on-off operations then it'll be an overkill to me because that functionality would have been possible with a simple DFF. If you want something like separation the short and long (set with PDT) then ignore what I said. Apart from that, the switching regulator will start immediately at first power-on (TPS's EN will be held high until the first PB comes). Is this what you want?

Comment: The reason I went for the LTC2954-1 was to that the interrupt pin could be used to allow me perform some cleaning up tasks on the esp32 before the power cut off. Will the TPS turn on immediately on power up due to the pull up resister I have place on TPS's EN? Or because of the way I've connected the LTC2954?